# TSLint appears to not apply costum rule?

Tags: typescript, tslint

So, I've been trying to TSLint costum rules to work, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get it to work.

I've wrote this custom rule, compiled it and put it in the corresponding folder:

```
//filename is interfacePascalCaseAndPrefixRule.ts 
import * as Lint from "tslint"; 
import * as ts from "typescript";

export class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
  static FAILURE_STRING =
    "Interfaces have to be Pascal cased and prefixed with an I (first two letters are capitalized).";

  public apply(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): Lint.RuleFailure[] {
    return this.applyWithWalker(new Walk(sourceFile, this.getOptions()));
  }
}

class Walk extends Lint.RuleWalker {
  protected visitInterfaceDeclaration(node: ts.InterfaceDeclaration) {
    this.addFailureAtNode(node, Rule.FAILURE_STRING);
    super.visitInterfaceDeclaration(node);
  }
}
```

To my understanding, this should raise an error for every interface declaration it finds. (Ignore the fact that this is pointless and the file name does not correspond to it's supposed function, this is for pure testing purposes.)

I've put the resulting interfacePascalCaseAndPrefixRule.ts in the rules/ - folder of a TypeScript project. The `tslint.json` looks like:

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "rules/"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "interface-pascal-case-and-prefix": true, // <-- This is the costum rule that doesn't do shit
    "class-name": true, //Enforces pascal case for classes eg. "MyClass"
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces",
      4
    ], //4 spaces as indents (is probably broken)
    "align": [
      true,
      "statements",
      "members"
    ], //aligns things. (might be broken as well)
    "encoding": true //encoding is UTF-8
  }
}
```

The `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

And when I run tslint, literally nothing happens (even though it definitely should raise some errors). The console output looks like:

```
:~/Desktop/bubblesbot$ tslint -p .
:~/Desktop/bubblesbot$
```

TSLint appears to be in working conditions as it does raise a bunch of errors when I add `"extends": "tslint:recommended"` to my `tslint.json`.

The implementation for the rule seems also the be found, since it raises an error when I purposely misspell it in the `tslint.json` file.

Any idea why this behaves the way it does? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to register TypeScript parsing for `node`, so before invoking `tslint`, install `ts-node` first and change the call to:

```sh
# if using yarn
$(yarn bin)/ts-node $(yarn bin)/tslint -p .
# if using npm
$(npm bin)/ts-node $(yarn bin)/tslint -p .
```

I also couldn't get TS rules to load unless they were compiled to JS first; this should resolve the problem.